# SQL INNER JOIN, @Parameter - does not filter results

Tags: c#, sql-server, inner-join

Thank you in advance for any advice you are able to give me.

**What I'm trying to achieve**: I have a combobox that I want to populate with table1 / columnC, sorted by matches in table1 / columnB and table2 / columnB.

For example: I want to display all of Roberts potatoes, not everyone's potatoes.

I have created a stored procedure for this. It currently looks like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[myProcedure]
    @myParameter nvarchar
AS
    SELECT columnA, columnB, columnC
    FROM table1
    INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.columnB = table2.columnB
    WHERE table1.columnB = @myParameter
```

Data set:

```
DataSet MyDataSet() 
{
   DataSet ds = new DataSet();

   using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
   using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapater("myProcedure", con)) 
   {
      da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

      //the line below gives value to my parameter, which in this case is a WinForms label
      //with the table1/columnB, table2/columnB value (the name that I wish to sort by)
      da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@myParameter", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = label.Text.ToString();
      da.Fill(ds);
   }

   return ds;
}
```

Populating my combobox (code is in form load event):

```
try 
{
    DataSet ds2 = MyDataSet();
    myComboBox.DataSource = ds2.Tables[0];
    myComboBox.DisplayMember = "columnC";
    myComboBox.ValueMember = "columnA"; // hidden ID row
} 
catch (Exception ex) 
{
    // messageboxcode
}
```

Oh, and, if it matters, all my columns are nvarchar except for table1/columnA, which is int.

Hope I make sense and that someone is able to give me a hint or two.
In regards to what I've tried to fix this, being new to SQL, I have read documentation, watched tutorials and generally spent hours trying to figure this out. I just can't for some reason! :-)

Comment: If you omit the length  nvarchar in a parameter of  a stored procedure, it defaults to one character. For example: nvarchar is a synonym for nvarchar(1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can say that your stored procedure is malformed because you don't have a length on `nvarchar()`.  **Never use `char` and related types in SQL Server without a length parameter.**. The default varies by context and assuming the default does what you want just leads to hard to debug errors (ahem).

In the absence of other information, you can use `(max)`, but I would suggest that you use an appropriate value for the length of the parameter:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].myProcedure (
     @myParameter nvarchar(max)
) AS
BEGIN
    SELECT columnA, columnB, columnC
    FROM table1 JOIN
         table2
         ON table1.columnB = table2.columnB
   WHERE table1.columnB = @myParameter;
END;
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm! A bit annoyed it was just something so trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Add the order like:

```
    order by table1.columnB,table2.columnB
```